# Display wind direction over wind magnitude in R using Levelplot

Tags: r, levelplot

I have converted U and V component of wind to wind direction and **magnitude**. But didn't able to map this data using levelplot.

```
 library(raster)
 library(rgdal)
 library(rasterVis)
 library(lattice)
 library(grid)

Ucomplist <- list.files(path = "F:/ShareBoth/yearly_variable_data/rasters/Ucomp_annual/Ucomp_annual/", full.names = TRUE)
length(Ucomplist)
U <- brick(Ucomplist)

Vcomplist <- list.files(path = "F:/ShareBoth/yearly_variable_data/rasters/Vcomp_annual/Vcomp_annual/", full.names = TRUE)
length(Vcomplist)
V <- brick(Vcomplist)

wd <- (180/pi)*(atan2(U,V))
ws <- sqrt(U^2+V^2)
```

data link

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PwABGUDBVUWi50Vfn9pmC-Dyjkpmtyny?usp=sharing

expected output:

[image: wind direction in vector form with magnitude of wind speed]

thanks in advance

Comment: Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code (including listing non-base R packages), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(x=...,y=...)`), and expected output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: sorry I am new here, I have edited my question. please check it now

Comment: That's a great start, thanks for improving the question a lot! I know that sometimes this kind of data can be difficult to share; links can (and often do) go stale, rendering this question unreproducible. If there are static datasets somewhere that also support this type of data (perhaps as part of an R package), that would be better sample data for questions on SO. Lastly, you show code for calculating, but don't show any warnings/errors or any attempt to plot. Where exactly are you having problems?

Comment: thanks a lot, actually I want to map the wind speed and magnitude as given in sample maps above. But didn't find any clue. If you can help me in this regard, That'll be great.

Comment: You should take a look at the `rasterVis::vectorplot` function. You will find examples [here](https://oscarperpinan.github.io/rastervis/#vectorplot) and [here](https://oscarperpinan.github.io/bookvis/spatial.html#vector).